# Cannot load rspec/rails (LoadError) when RAILS_ENV=test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rspec-rails

I'm trying to run a spec with `rails_helper` import. Like that:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Dummy' do
  it 'need pass' do
    expect(1).to eq 1
  end
end
```

When run `rspec` its wokrs fine but when pass RAILS_ENV=test that raise a import error => https://pastebin.com/TLazJhzh

A import info is which I'm running all that on docker. That is my docker files:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils \
    build-essential \
    git \
    bash \
    vim \
    curl \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
  && truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile* /app/

RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries

RUN bundle check || bundle install

COPY . ./
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "./wait && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: ${ENV_FILE-.env.development}
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: db:3306
      WAIT_HOST_CONNECT_TIMEOUT: 10

  db:
    image: mysql:5
    command: --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
    volumes:
      - mysql_5_volume:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

volumes:
  mysql_5_volume:
```

For run rspec I'm doing:
`ENV_FILE=.env.test docker-compose run api bundle exec rspec` => fails
`docker-compose run api bundle exe rspec` => works

Content of `.env.test` file:

```
RAILS_ENV=test

DATABASE_ADAPTER=mysql2
DATABASE_ENCODING=utf8
DATABASE_USERNAME=root
DATABASE_HOSTNAME=db
DATABASE_PORT=3306
DATABASE_POOL=5
DATABASE_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Do you have `rspec_rails` in you gemfile?

Comment: Yes. `gem 'rspec-rails'` inside development and test groups.